# Get a number's "out of ten" value when the total is a variable

Tags: logic

So I have a set of marks. They are in the format marks obtained / total marks (`m` / `t`). What I would like is this marks' "out of ten" value. Like for a set of 40/100 the answer would be 4 and for a set of 20/50 the answer would be 4 again. For a set of 24/56 the answer would be... I don't know really, that's what I need help for. I need to convert the marks in a "out of ten" value.

I can easily do this when I know the total but in my case the total is a variable so right now I am having a brain fart moment.

I have had a look at other questions here, and mine is not as fancy as others, I am not particularly proud of my math abilities and it's midnight and I need to finish this now, so I can really use some help.

Comment: $10\frac{m}{t}$ should give you a value from $0-10$ if $m<t$ and both are positive. You could then round this if you want an integer value.

Comment: @ruler501 Exactly what I needed! Thanks! As I said brain fart... :P

Comment: I'm not sure where [logic] fits here. But I have no idea where this question does fit. Certainly not in [logic], though.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila I am new to this SE site and I had no idea where it would fit either, and a tag was required to post the question so I picked one that sounded remotely relevant. Logic's description included 'math logic' and considering my question was very basic, I went with it.

Comment: Mathematical logic is not "the logic that you apply when doing mathematics".

Comment: Apparently so... As I said, new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$10\frac{m}{t}$ gives you a value from $0-10$ Round this to get an integer value if you need to.

There are some conditions. $|m|<|t|$ and $\text{sgn}(m)=\text{sgn}(t)$

Comment: A rather simple and elegant solution for my non-pro self.